# How to run a PHP script placed on a remote server via ssh from local server, both servers are running on redhat linux?

Tags: php, linux, bash, ssh

Using PUTTY as ssh client

The below errors appear on the console after running the script. I am not sure whats wrong here as the script runs perfectly fine on the remote server but when i try running it from local server, it doesn't work. Both machines have different applications running on them ,both support PHP although different versions. Maybe i am doing something wrong here

```
  root@remoteserver> php -v
  PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul 25 2016 05:47:24)
  Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

  root@localserver> php -v
  PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jul 22 2016 04:50:37)
  Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

**Errors:**

```
    root@localserver> ssh remoteserver "/path/script" 
    PHP Warning:  include_once(/mach7gui/oam/data/ui/m7in/php- 
    scripts/inc/AMGT_map.php): failed to open stream: No such file or 
    directory in /path/script on line 5
    PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 
   '/mach7gui/oam/data/ui/m7in/php-scripts/inc/AMGT_map.php' for inclusion 
   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /path/script on 
   line 5

   sh: /tools/mon/db_wrap: No such file or directory
   sh: /tools/mon/db_wrap: No such file or directory
   sh: /tools/mon/db_wrap: No such file or directory
   sh: /tools/mon/db_wrap: No such file or directory
   sh: /tools/mon/db_wrap: No such file or directory
   sh: /tools/mon/db_wrap: No such file or directory

   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could 
   not find driver' in /path/script:41
   Stack trace:
   #0 /path/script(41): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=;dbn...', '', '')
   #1 {main}
   thrown in /path/script on line 41
```

Comment: Did you try with absolute path in your script ? If does can you show  script ?

Comment: Yeah i gave the full path to the script but still no luck

Comment: "although different versions" + 'could not find driver'... so maybe you need to install something to your local server? Also format your question to a more readable form (at least format error as a code)

Comment: i mean not to the script, but all path inside the script. 
"No such file or directory sh: /tools/mon/db_wrap: No such file or director" <- path to "db_wrap" start from /tools/ ? Or there is something before like /home/xxx/tools/ on remote server.

Comment: right so you mean to say that i should check on the remote server whether the mentioned path in the script actually exists or not? if it doesn't exist then it won't be able to run it even though the script runs flawlessly when executing without ssh on remote server?

@x00 I edited the errors portion hope its more readable now.

Comment: Maybe I will ask in different way,  your script ( if you are directly on server  ) is running properly if you run it from different path than he is located ?

Comment: i can call the script from whatever path i am on (on the remote server) as there's a command on that server for calling that script. All i need to do is type "script.sh" to call the script and it works but the local server doesn't have that functionality as we have a different application n the local server.  Let show you

root@remoteserver> pwd
/root

root@remoteserver> locate script.sh

/home/m7istp.7.3.6.b1/m7istp/ems/cli/script.sh

root@remoteserver>

Comment: it seems like the script requires some files that or not exists or can not be accessed. Did you check they exist and you can access them?

Comment: Ok, so on your remote server file "db_wrap" is on this path "/tools/mon/db_wrap" or different ? ( full path )

Comment: its on a different path

Comment: @JavierGálvez What i am unable to understand here is that why the script cannot be accessed over ssh even though it runs without any problem on the remote server? What is it that the local server needs to run the script on the remote server via ssh? The files exist but for example the full path isn't in the script because when you call the script on the remote server through a command that is unique to the remote server ,it  re-directs to the directory where the files mentioned in the script are placed. Why can't i do the same through local server by ssh?

Comment: @Goldriver when you run a script through ssh you don't make a login in the remote machine (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-execute-command-using-ssh/) and when you use a require into your php, files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). Remember you don't have $PATH because you don't login

Comment: @JavierGálvez I cannot modify the script as its a system script and i do not have permission to modify. I am not sure if i can use include or require in the php script as i just need to call the script from the local server and execute it to view related output.

Comment: @Goldriver try to execute the command through *sh*: `ssh your-user@your-server "sh -c 'your-command' "`